# Traceback error for variable not assigned

Tags: python

I am getting an error that I don't understand in this short program. The errors read

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 40, in <module>
    main()
   line 35, in main
    totalCost = cleanCost * sizeFactor
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cleanCost' referenced before assignment
```

It says that cleanCost is not assigned, but I believe I did assign it in the set price based on cleaning type area unless I am mistaken. If that is not properly assigned how do I assign it so that the variable can change based on input?

```
def main():
 
    #Display welcome message
    print ("Hello, welcome to Hannah’s Cleaning Service!")

    #prompt user for house size
    houseSize = int(input("How many bedrooms is your home?"))

    #prompt user for type of cleaning
    cleanType = str(input("What type of cleaning would you like \n 1=floors, \n 2=windows, \n 3=bathrooms, or \n 4=dusting?"))

    #set price based on cleaning type
    if (cleanType == 1):
        cleanCost = 60
    elif (cleanType == 2):
        cleanCost = 50
    elif (cleanType == 3):
        cleanCost = 40
    elif (cleanType == 4):
        cleanCost = 30

    #set multiplication factor based on house size
    if (houseSize <= 2):
        sizeFactor = 1
    elif (houseSize == 3):
        sizeFactor = 2
    elif (houseSize >= 4):
        sizeFactor = 3

    #Calculate total price
    totalCost = cleanCost * sizeFactor

    #Display total cost
    print ("Your total is $totalCost")

main()
```

Comment: Why did you write `str()` when asking the user for `cleanType`? You did something else when asking for `houseSize`.

Comment: Thank you! I had changed the code around completely from my original plan and not caught that error.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into an issue of scope/visibility.  Since in your initial iteration of the code, "cleaningCost" is going in and out of scope within the various "if" tests".  Following, is a tweaked version of your code with the two work variables initialized.

```
def main():
 
    #Display welcome message
    print ("Hello, welcome to Hannah’s Cleaning Service!")

    #prompt user for house size
    houseSize = int(input("How many bedrooms is your home?"))

    #prompt user for type of cleaning
    cleanType = str(input("What type of cleaning would you like \n 1=floors, \n 2=windows, \n 3=bathrooms, or \n 4=dusting?"))

    cleanCost  = 0          # Need to be initialized at this scope level
    sizeFactor = 1

    #set price based on cleaning type
    if (cleanType == "1"):      # Need to be checked as alphanumeric values
        cleanCost = 60
    elif (cleanType == "2"):
        cleanCost = 50
    elif (cleanType == "3"):
        cleanCost = 40
    elif (cleanType == "4"):
        cleanCost = 30

    #set multiplication factor based on house size
    if (houseSize <= 2):
        sizeFactor = 1
    elif (houseSize == 3):
        sizeFactor = 2
    elif (houseSize >= 4):
        sizeFactor = 3

    #Calculate total price
    totalCost = cleanCost * sizeFactor

    #Display total cost
    print ("Your total is", totalCost)

main()
```

Also, note that I tweaked the "cleanType" tests to be alphanumeric tests since your input statement sets up variable "cleanType" as a string.

With those tweaks, following was some sample output on my terminal.

```
@Una:~/Python_Programs/Cleaning$ python3 Cleaning.py 
Hello, welcome to Hannah’s Cleaning Service!
How many bedrooms is your home?4
What type of cleaning would you like 
 1=floors, 
 2=windows, 
 3=bathrooms, or 
 4=dusting?1
Your total is 180
```

The big take-away is the scope of variables.  Give those tweaks a try.